# Building an iterable and hierarchical data structure with type-safe members

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am writing an application that calculates results of a user-defined physics study. I want to have these results in a class that can be serialized and deserialized, cloned, etc. - a data structure.
This data structure is very complex and has a lot of members, therefore I want to have multi-level hierarchy in it:

```
Study results:
1. Hydrostatics
1.1 Waterplane
1.1.1 LOA
1.1.2 BOA
1.1.3 LCB
//etc.
1.2. Immersion
1.2.1 Heel
1.2.2 Trim
1.2.3 Displacement
//etc.
2. Hydrodynamics
2.1 Lift force
2.2 Resistance
//etc.
```

The final members (study result objects that actually hold data) may be on different levels of this hierarchy - some nested deeper than others. These members will also have different types (created from different classes), but they all implement the same interface `IStudyResult`.

I need to be able to retrieve all these members from the `studyResults` object by calling, for example `studyResults.GetMembers()` which would return all members that implement `IStudyResult`, regardless of where they are in the hierarchy.

I also need to be able to do the same on any lower point in the hierarchy, for example `hydrostatics.GetMembers()`, which would return only it's members that implement `IStudyResult`.

And I also need to be able to address these objects individually in a type-safe way, for example `studyResults.hydrostatics.waterplane.loa`.

So far, the best I came up with is to create this data structure as a class hierarchy, for example:

```
public class StudyResults
{
   public Hydrostatics hydrostatics;
}

public class Hydrostatics
{
   public Waterplane waterplane;
   public Immersion immersion;
}

public class Waterplane
{
   public LOA loa; //implements IStudyResult; 
   public BOA boa; //implements IStudyResult; 
   public LCB lcb; //implements IStudyResult; 
}
//etc.
```

And then put references to each `IStudyResult` implementing object into different lists in each hierarchical class, as well as one big list at the top of hierarchy. However, this is very difficult to maintain, as each time I add a new object somewhere in the hierarchy, I need to "register" it manually in each list. I could probably automate this by having higher-level lists obtain references to these objects by calling `GetMembers()` on the lower-level hierarchy objects, but I would still need to add these objects to at least one list manually.

I suppose this adding to lists can be done with reflection, but I was told that usually if one needs reflection then the implementation is likely flawed in the first place.

Another idea is to define StudyResults as a list/dictionary, where each member object is instantiated in that list/dictionary in the first place. But this would not provide me with any hierarchy, and filtering out particular group of members would be very difficult - I would have to create additional lists, or each member object would have to "know" it's place in the hierarchy with some sort of tags. Also, the names of these member objects would have to be stored as a string, so they would not be type-safe (I suppose I could get around this by using names enumerator, but this complicates things even further).

I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here, and there must be a cannon implementation of such data structures. Can anyone advise?